# Why is this jQuery selector not returning any elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select all sub-elements and filter those with certain attributes. One of the elements is a contenteditible div that contains a data-required attribute(see HTML below). When I use the following selector, it returns 1:

```
$("#mail-container").filter('[required], [data-required]').length
```

But when I execute the following, 0 is returned:

```
form.contents().filter('[data-required]').length;
```

Note, the following returns 9:

```
form.contents().length;
```

**EDIT**

The following function is called as follows:

```
$("#send-email").on('mouseup', function (e) {
    if (!validateRequiredFields($("#form-email-preview"))) return false;
    var data = {};
    data.action = "manuscript-request-email";
    data["writers-id"] = $("#writer-id").val();
    data["account-id"] = localStorage.getItem("account-id");
    data.subject = $("#subject").val();
    data.body = $("#mail-container").html();
    ajax('post', 'php/writers.php', data, sentEmail);
    function sentEmail(result) {
        console.log("email-res=" + result);
        return2table();
    }
});

function validateRequiredFields(form) {
    var $reqFlds = form.contents().filter('[required], [data-required]');
    var ret = true;
    debugger
    $reqFlds.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var result = ($this.eq("input, select, textarea")) ? $this.val() : $this.text();
        if (!$.trim(result)) {
            $this.prop('data-toggle=popover', true);
            $this.show();
            $this.popover("destroy").popover({ content: "Please fill out this field.", placement: 'bottom' });
            $this.popover('show');
            $this.focus();
            ret = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="form-email-preview" style="margin-top: 24px;">
    <div id="main-container" class="hidden" style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 6px;  border-radius: 8px;">
        <span><b>Subject:</b></span><input id="subject" type="text" value="Manuscript Request" style="display: inline-block" />
        <p><b>Email:</b></p>
        <div id="mail-container" contenteditable data-toggle="popover" data-required data-placement="top" data-title ="Required field" style="display: inline-block"></div><br/>
        <p id="buttons" class="hidden">
            <input type='button' id='send-email' class='btn btn-custom-success' value='Send Email' /><span>   </span>
            <button id='cancel-email' class = 'btn btn-danger'>Cancel</button>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="current-row" class="hidden"></div>
    <input id="current-checkbox" type="checkbox" class="hidden" />
    <input id="current-tr" type="number" class="hidden" />
</form>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: can you paste the complete code

Comment: There is a lot of JS code. What, in particular would you like to see?

Comment: when you are calling validateRequiredFields()

Comment: "form" isn't a jQuery object.

Comment: @TyrionGraphiste - of course it is, it's clearly passed to the function.

Comment: @adeneo Not in this case, it's just the reference, not a jQuery object. He should have "form.find is not a function" error in console.

Comment: There are no errors in console. Also, see that form.contents().length returns 9.

Comment: @TyrionGraphiste - yes in this case, he's doing `func( $("#form-email-preview") )` and there's no way that could be anything other *than* the jQuery object in `function func(form) {...`

Comment: Use console.log() for debugging, it should be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There simply are no matching elements ?

In this context, you're doing

```
validateRequiredFields( $("#form-email-preview") );

function validateRequiredFields(form) {

    var $reqFlds =  form.contents().filter('[required], [data-required]');

    ....
```

`form.contents()` gets you the nine children of the form, that's including the textnodes

```
<form id="form-email-preview" style="margin-top: 24px;">
    <!-- text node here -->                                           <!-- 1 -->
    <div id="main-container" ...></div>                               <!-- 2 -->
    <!-- text node here -->                                           <!-- 3 -->
    <div id="current-row" class="hidden"></div>                       <!-- 4 -->
    <!-- text node here -->                                           <!-- 5 -->
    <input id="current-checkbox" type="checkbox" class="hidden" />    <!-- 6 -->
    <!-- text node here -->                                           <!-- 7 -->
    <input id="current-tr" type="number" class="hidden" />            <!-- 8 -->
    <!-- text node here -->                                           <!-- 9 -->
</form>
```

That's nine, none of them are the elements you're looking for, and here's what `contents()` does

> Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements,
>   including text and comment nodes.

Then you filter those nine elements, and only those nine, as `filter()` doesn't filter children of those nine, only those

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or
>   pass the function's test.

You have a set of nine elements, none of them with the attributes you're looking for, and you filter that set, and you end up with ... nothing

What you wanted was just

```
var $reqFlds = form.find('[required], [data-required]');
```

As a sidenote, read the documentation for the methods you're using, and it should be clear what they do, for instance these are incorrect

```
$this.eq("input, select, textarea") // eq() accepts a number only

$this.prop('data-toggle=popover', true); // accepts a property, 
                                         // not an entire attribute, with the value ?
```

Comment: Once again, you have come to my rescue, @adeno. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example code without any context, it looks like `form` represents a DOM node instead of a jQuery object.

Just wrap it in the jQuery method to make it a jQuery object then it should work fine.

```
var $reqFlds = $(form).contents().filter('[required], [data-required]');
```

Comment: Please refer to the EDIT. The function is being passed a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the cause of your problem but in the first example you are using the $("#mail-container") element. In your code (!validateRequiredFields($("#form-email-preview"))) you referring to the $("#form-email-preview") element. I hope it helps